# Misunderstanding of the OOP in a chess game design in java

Tags: swing, oop, chess

I've a problem with code that I'm writing to practice my java skills.
I'm trying to write a chess game. Anyway, in my project I have a class called ChessGUI which contains the GUI and the methods I need to play (multiplayer). I'm willing to change the code later to a MVC pattern so it can be easier to read/edit/understand.
I've an abstract class called Figure and i extended it in 12 classes (6 figures per color):

[image: like this:]

However in my ChessGui class I have a method called CheckAvailableSquares() which I call whenever a piece on the board has been selected (by a mouse click) to show me on the board the available squares which I can move my selected piece to.

```
 private void CheckAvailableSquares(Figure figure){
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++){
            if (row == figure.getRowPos() && col == figure.getColPos()) //bypass the actual square where my piece stands
                continue;
            if (figure.isValidMove(board,figure.getRowPos(), figure.getColPos(),row,col)){
                board[row][col].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In every figure sub-class there is a method called isValidMove() which becomes the current position of the piece and the wanted position and return a boolean value if the move is valid.

As you know the pawn can move 2 squares per time on it's first move, that's why I added a boolean attribute to the classes WhitePawn&BlackPawn called firstMovePlayed. It has the false value and whenever the isMoveValid() method is called and the wanted move is valid it should be changed to true. like that:

```
public class WhitePawn extends Figure {
private boolean firstMovePlayed = false;

public WhitePawn(){
    super.setColor(Color.WHITE);
}

@Override
public boolean isValidMove(Square[][] board, int currentRow, int currentCol, int wantedRow, int wantedCol){
    int rowDelta = currentRow - wantedRow; //no Math.abs because a pawn can't move backwards.
    int colDelta = Math.abs(wantedCol - currentCol);

    //if we have an own piece on the wanted square
    if (!board[wantedRow][wantedCol].isEmpty() && board[wantedRow][wantedCol].getFigure().getColor().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
        return false;
    }
    //on the first move a pawn can move 2 square at a time, and when moving 2 square he can't capture. A pawn can't move two square if there is another piece in the way. TODO: en passant ??????
    if (rowDelta == 2 && colDelta == 0 && board[wantedRow][wantedCol].isEmpty() && board[wantedRow + 1][wantedCol].isEmpty() && !firstMovePlayed) {
        firstMovePlayed = true;
        return true;
    }
    else if (rowDelta == 1 && colDelta == 1 && !board[wantedRow][wantedCol].isEmpty()) { //capture
        if (board[wantedRow][wantedCol].getFigure().getColor() != board[currentRow][currentCol].getFigure().getColor())
            firstMovePlayed = true;
        return true;
    }
    else if (rowDelta == 1 && colDelta == 0 && board[wantedRow][wantedCol].isEmpty()) { //moving one square forward without a capture
        firstMovePlayed = true;
        return true;
    }
    //those were the only possibilities to move a pawn
    return false;
}}
```

**The problem is:**
whenever I call the method CheckAvailableSquares() to check the availability of the squares the firstMovePlayed boolean will be set to true!!

I'm really sorry for taking too long of your time but I really can't figure it out :/

> here is the rest of the relevant code from ChessGui class:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //looking for the square which fired the ActionListener:
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == e.getSource()){
                processClick(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
private void processClick(int i, int j){
    if(bufRow == 99 && bufCol == 99){                        //select a figure to move and wait for the next click
        if (board[i][j].isEmpty()) {                              //if there is no figure on the square that has benn clicked
            System.out.println("no Figures on this square");
            return;
        }
        else {//save the chosen square (button) in buffers so that we can move it later.
            //decide who's turn it is:
            if (board[i][j].getFigure().getColor().equals(Color.WHITE) && !whiteToPlay)
                System.out.println("It's black's turn to play!");
            else if (board[i][j].getFigure().getColor().equals(Color.BLACK) && !blackToPlay)
                System.out.println("It's white's turn to play!");
            if ((board[i][j].getFigure().getColor().equals(Color.WHITE) && whiteToPlay) || board[i][j].getFigure().getColor().equals(Color.BLACK) && blackToPlay) {
                board[i][j].setHighleightedIcon(board[i][j].getFigure().getHilightedIcon()); //change the icon of the chosen square
                bufRow = i;     //save the chosen figure to move it later
                bufCol = j;
                System.out.println("Selectd figure on Raw: " + bufRow + " Column: " + bufCol);
                switchTurns();
                CheckAvailableSquares(board[bufRow][bufCol].getFigure());
            }
        }
    }
    else
        moveFigure(i, j);
}
private void moveFigure(int wantedRow, int wantedCol) {
    if (board[bufRow][bufCol].getFigure().isValidMove(board, bufRow, bufCol, wantedRow, wantedCol)) {            // check if the move is valid for the figure
        // if (board[wantedRow][wantedCol].isEmpty()) {                                                                                 //if the wanted square is empty (not a capture)
        //move the figure to the wanted square after deleting it from the old square
        board[wantedRow][wantedCol].setFigure(board[bufRow][bufCol].getFigure());
        board[wantedRow][wantedCol].setSquareIcon(board[bufRow][bufCol].getFigure().getIcon());
        board[bufRow][bufCol].emptySquare();
        //update the location of the piece
        board[wantedRow][wantedCol].getFigure().setNewPos(wantedRow,wantedCol);
        System.out.println("Moved [" + bufRow + ", " + bufCol + "] To: [" + wantedRow + ", " + wantedCol + "].");
        //reset the buffers
        bufRow = 99;
        bufCol = 99;
        resetSquaresColors();
        /*}
        else if (!board[wantedRow][wantedCol].isEmpty()){                                                                                         //if it's a capture
            if(board[wantedRow][wantedCol].getFigure().getColor() != board[bufRow][bufCol].getFigure().getColor()) {      //can't capture own pieces!
                board[wantedRow][wantedCol].setFigure(board[bufRow][bufCol].getFigure());
                board[wantedRow][wantedCol].setSquareIcon(board[wantedRow][wantedCol].getFigure().getIcon());
                board[bufRow][bufCol].emptySquare();
                //update the location of the piece
                board[wantedRow][wantedCol].getFigure().setRowPos(wantedRow);
                board[wantedRow][wantedCol].getFigure().setColPos(wantedCol);
                System.out.println("Moved [" + bufRow + ", " + bufCol + "] To: [" + wantedRow + ", " + wantedCol + "].");
                //reset the buffers
                bufRow = 99;
                bufCol = 99;
            }
        }*/
    } else {      //if it's not a valid move
        board[bufRow][bufCol].setIcon(board[bufRow][bufCol].getFigure().getIcon());
        //reset the buffers
        bufRow = 99;
        bufCol = 99;
        resetSquaresColors();
        System.out.println("Not a valid move");
        switchTurns();
    }
}
private void CheckAvailableSquares(Figure figure){
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++){
            if (row == figure.getRowPos() && col == figure.getColPos()) //bypass the actual square where my piece stands
                continue;
            if (figure.isValidMove(board,figure.getRowPos(), figure.getColPos(),row,col)){
                Square sqr = board[row][col];
                if (sqr.isEmpty()) //if the square is empty
                    sqr.setAvailableIcon(new ImageIcon("Icons/available_square.png"));
                else //if there is a piece on the square
                    sqr.setAvailableIcon(sqr.getFigure().getAvailableIcon());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Thanks alot & forgive any mistakes in my poor English!**

Comment: Don't change the state when checking for 'a valid move'. If the move is valid, *then* move the piece and "advance" the game state.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
what do you mean by advancing the game state please?

Comment: ie. when a piece is moved it has a 'moved counter' incremented. This is a change in state that is *separate* from checking the state prior.

Comment: So, `Figure.isValidMove(..)` and `Figure.move(..)/moved(..)` are two *separate* methods (a query and then a command), and `isValidMove` does not change any state. In general, methods that start with "is" or "can" or "get" are should *not* change any visible state.

Comment: so you suggest to write the move method inside the the Figure class instead of having it in the ChessGui?
Nice idea!
thank you!

Comment: In the final code that might be good, but for now it could be like this: `board.move(/* update piece locations on the GUI board */); figure.moved(/* figure does any movement-related stuff it needs */)`. Maybe `onMoved` would be a more clear name in this case? Remember in come cases (like a castle), *multiple* pieces are moved during the same turn - that'd be a bit more work, but one step at a time..

Comment: that was really helpful! thank you :)